# Как сделать доступной в терминале команду pub?

Tags: dart

Ставлю `dart` по туториалу:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
 sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
 sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install dart
```

После этого мне уже предлагают использовать `pub`, например

```
pub global activate aqueduct
```

однако такой команды нет

```
Command 'pub' not found, did you mean:...
```

При этом если в `VS Code` создать в папочке `pubspec.yaml` и прописать в нем зависимости, то при сохранении файла эти зависимости ставятся, а во всплывающем окошке пишут

```
pub get: running
```

Как мне поставить `pub` чтобы можно было запускать эту команду руками в терминале?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вам бы, научиться использовать официальную документацию.](https://dart.dev/get-dart) Проблема в том, что вы не добавили папку с Dart SDK в PATH. Вот в какой последовательности необходимо устанавливать Dart SDK:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dart
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"
```

После этого можно использовать команду `pub` в терминале.

Comment: Да, действительно, нужно внимательнее читать доку. Я почему-то подумал, что это действие нужно делать только если устанавливаешь предварительно скачанный deb пакет. Спасибо.

Comment: предлагаю так же ответить на этот вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000560/how-do-i-make-the-pub-command-available-in-the-terminal?noredirect=1#comment104255791_59000560

Comment: @muturgan там вам сразу ответили в комментариях (правда под MacOS), можете создать ответ на свой вопрос сами)